# Tableview display alert error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I am writing a simple tableview app, when tapping the row, a alert shows up.

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *rowValue =self.greekLetters[indexPath.row];
   // NSString *message=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"You selected%@!",rowValue];

   if (indexPath.row==0) {
        NSString *message=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"This is course aaaaa",rowValue];
    }

    if (indexPath.row==1) {
        NSString *message=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"This is course aaaaa"];
    }


    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Course introduction" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Return to courses list" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [alert show];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

However, Xcode doesn't like my if statement here, while the following statement works.

```
NSString *message=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"You selected%@!",rowValue];
```

Could anyone give me an example of how to use the message here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with scope.  You need to declare message before the if statement:

```
NSString *message;

if (indexPath.row==0) {
    message=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"This is course aaaaa",rowValue];
}

else if (indexPath.row==1) {
    message=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"This is course aaaaa"];
}

UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Course introduction" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Return to courses list" otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alert show];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

However, if the course number is determined by the row number do:

```
NSString *rowValue =self.greekLetters[indexPath.row];

NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"This is course %@",rowValue];

UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Course introduction" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Return to courses list" otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alert show];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

Comment: But it's always safer to declare the variable beforehand :)

Comment: Is that unique to objective-c?  I would think that only code inside the block would know about variables declared in that block.

Comment: And btw.. you're right about the %d ;-)  Didn't see that rowValue was added without the token.

Comment: Oooh, you're right, this is a scope issue! My bad. Obj-C is no different from other languages when it comes to scope.

Comment: Thanks all for your reply. I use Josh's method, but it doesn't show "This is the course XXXX" in the alert. Any reason please?

Comment: Is "XXXX" defined by the row number?  If so you can do  NSString *message=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"This is course %i",indexPath.row];  and you don't need the if statement at all.  So if row 0 is selected, it will say "This is course 0".  I have added this to my answer

Comment: Thanks Josh, XXXX is with some specific name, that is why I want to use characters here. But I don't know why " THis is the course XXX" doesn't show up

Comment: I added this to the answer now. The rowValue (a greek letter i guess) is a string, so you need the %@ token

Comment: Also, I noticed that in the UIAlertView alloc init, you have nil, nil for the otherButtonTitles parameter.  You only need one nil.

Comment: Sure thing.  Anytime :)

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to include `%@` in the first if-statement.

```
NSString *message= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"This is course aaaaa %@",rowValue];
```

By the way, there's no need to do `[[NSString alloc] init]` at all, just use `[NSString stringWithFormat:...]`

Comment: @rmaddy Well, the OP has not included any error message in the question.

Comment: By looking at the code, the issue is clearly the problem with the scope of the `message` variable. Forgetting the `%d` will not cause an error. The message simply won't contain the value.